# Another way to fill value in decreasing and increasing order at array objects index

Tags: javascript

I try to fill a decreasing and increasing value at array of objects index.

 Anyone have a another way to solve this problem? Here is my solution.

```js
let myData = [{
  value: 0
}, {
  value: 0
}, {
  value: 0
}, {
  value: 0
}, {
  value: 0
}];

function fillAtIndex(index, value, data) {
  
  let decreaseValue = value;
  let increaseValue = value;
  
  for (let i = index; i < data.length; ++i) {
    data[i].value = increaseValue;
    ++increaseValue
  }
  
  for (let i = index; i >= 0; --i) {
    data[i].value = decreaseValue;
    --decreaseValue
  }
  
  return data;
}

myData = fillAtIndex(2, 10, myData);
console.log(myData);
```

Comment: **https://codereview.stackexchange.com/**

Comment: Your full code takes on average 0.025ms to perform, **why** do you need it to be faster?

Comment: Sorry, I should not need to mention faster, I just want to find another idea to implement this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following function (`numberSeries()`) with a given array of objects returns a new array of objects. Each object will have a given key that will have an incremented number. This function is reusable -- the second parameter (`keyName`) allows the user to edit or create a specific key. Details are commented in **Demo 1**. **Demo 2** is the streamlined less readable version of Demo 1

#### Demo 1

```js
const data = [{id: "", type: ""}, {id: 698, type: undefined}, {id: 0, type: "set"}, {type: ""}];

/* @Signature:
   numberSeries(array, keyName, initNum, initIdx)
** @Purpose: 
   * With a given array of objects it returns a new array of objects.
     Each object will have a given key that will have an incremented number.
** @Params:
   * array [Array]: An array of objects
   * keyName [String]: The name of the key that will be assigned an incremented number 
     on each object. 
     If an object does not have said key -- it will be added.
   * initNum [Number]: The number value to start with
   * initIdx [Number]{optional}: The index number to start with. 
     If undefined -- it defaults to 1
*/
const numberSeries = (array, keyName, initNum, initIdx, increment = 1) => {
  // Clone the array
  let cloneArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
  // Run the following on each object and return a new modified array of objects...
  let result = cloneArray.map(object => {
    /* 
    Expression adds the first number passed (initNum) to the incrementing number (increment) 
    and subtracts the first index number passed (initIdx)                
    */
    let diff = ((initNum += increment) - (initIdx * increment)) - increment;
    /* 
    Assign the result of the previous expression to the current object property  
    named by (keyName) parameter 
    */
    object[keyName] = diff;
    // return the modified object into the new array
    return object;
  });
  // return the new array of modified objectrs
  return result;
}

log(`Example 1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: 'id', assign 80 at index 2 and increment each value by 2`);
log(numberSeries(data, "id", 80, 2, 2));
log(` `);
log(`Example 2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: 'type', assign 5 at index 0 and increment each value by the default of 1 since the initIdx parameter wasn't defined`);
log(numberSeries(data, "type", 5, 0));
log(` `);
log(`Example 3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: '#', assign 3 at index 3 and increment each value by the default of 1 since the initIdx parameter wasn't defined`);
log(numberSeries(data, "#", 3, 3));

// Optional utility function to display console
function log(source, stringify = true) {
  let result = !stringify ? source : JSON.stringify(source);
  return console.log(result);
}
```

---

#### Demo 2

```js
const data = [{id: "", type: ""}, {id: 698, type: undefined}, {id: 0, type: "set"}, {type: ""}];

const numberSeries = (array, keyName, initNum, initIdx, increment = 1) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)).map(object => {
    object[keyName] = ((initNum += increment) - initIdx) - increment;
    return object;
});

log(`Example 1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: 'id', assign 80 at index 2 and increment each value by 2`);
log(numberSeries(data, "id", 80, 2, 2));
log(` `);
log(`Example 2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: 'type', assign 5 at index 0 and increment each value by the default of 1 since the initIdx parameter wasn't defined`);
log(numberSeries(data, "type", 5, 0));
log(` `);
log(`Example 3~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`);
log(`Change or create the key: '#', assign 3 at index 3 and increment each value by the default of 1 since the initIdx parameter wasn't defined`);
log(numberSeries(data, "#", 3, 3));

// Optional utility function to display console
function log(source, stringify = true) {
  let result = !stringify ? source : JSON.stringify(source);
  return console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can write it short hand, with a single loop or some variations of:

```
let myData = [{value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}, {value: 0}];

function fillAtIndex(index, value, data) {
    let diff = 0;
    let i = j = index;

    while (i<data.length && j>=0) {
        data[i] = value + diff;
        data[j] = value - diff;
        diff++; i++; j--;
    } 

    return data;
}

myData = fillAtIndex(2, 10, myData);
console.log(myData);
```

But, complexity wise it'll still be the same. For filling `n` elements, you need to do at least `n` operations, whether you process half of the items in one loop or half in another or do it all at once. You cannot do anything better than `O(n)` here.

Comment: Have you actually tested this? The code is wrong. I also wouldn't suggest posting an answer to a [tag:performance] question without including a benchmark demonstrating comparison. In simple cases like this, actual benchmarks are much more relevant than asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, it does work except the format of the output. Do you regard my answer as wrong because it outputs the values directly instead of wrapping it in another field `.value`?
I didn't paid attention to it because the question is asked for reducing the complexity. Furthermore, we can argue about benchmarking practices if there are other lazy operations, etc, etc.
Isn't it just plain math here?

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the iterations and the use of different variables and take a single loop with only one extra variable, for iterating the array.

```js
function fillAtIndex(index, value, data) {
    value -= index; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) data[i].value = value++;
    return data;
}

let myData = [{ value: 0 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 }, { value: 0 }];

myData = fillAtIndex(2, 10, myData);
console.log(myData);
```